# CMake how to check that exactly one option is selected?

Tags: cmake

Assuming I have 3 defined [options](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/option.html?highlight=option) in a CMakeLists file, for instance:

```
option(FIRST_OPT "<text1>" ON)
option(SECOND_OPT "text2>" OFF)
option(THIRD_OPT "<text3>" OFF)
```

**Exactly one option (of the three) should be selected**. Is there an elegant way/ Macro to verify it?

Currently I just check for all valid conditions
(which, for 3 options still looks reasonable but for larger groups is not practical):

```
(FIRST_OPT AND SECOND_OPT) OR 
(FIRST_OPT AND THIRD_OPT) OR 
(SECOND_OPT AND THIRD_OPT) OR 
(NOT (FIRST_OPT AND SECOND_OPT AND THIRD_OPT))
```

Comment: create a list with options and count ONs in the foreach loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of *mutually-exclusive* set of options use a **single** parameter with a string value:

```
set(OPT "FIRST" CACHE STRING "Provider choosen")
```

This parameter is visible to the user in the same extent, as one created by `option` command.

Because the parameter can have only a single value, you needn't to check whether at most one of your options is enabled.

By assigning `STRINGS` property of the parameter, you may tell a user which parameter's values can be used, and even provide drop-down list of them in the GUI:

```
set_property(CACHE OPT PROPERTY STRINGS "FIRST" "SECOND" "THIRD")
```

CMake itself doesn't check correctness of the parameter's value, but you may easily check it by yourself:

```
# Extract "STRINGS" property of the parameter
get_property(OPT_STRINGS CACHE OPT PROPERTY STRINGS)
# Check that value of the parameter is inside "STRINGS" list.
if (NOT OPT IN_LIST OPT_STRINGS)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Wrong value of the parameter 'OPT'")
endif
```

Comment: why do you use `CACHE` ?

Comment: Command `set(... CACHE ...)` defines a variable which could be set by a user (the person who will build your project). That variable is presented in CMake GUI and has a description (specified as last parameter for `set` command). Command `option`, which you use, is also intended for declare a variable for a user.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [nayab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1595504/nayab) comment:

```
option(FIRST_OPT "<text1>" ON)
option(SECOND_OPT "<text2>" OFF)
option(THIRD_OPT "<text3>" OFF)

set(COUNTER 0)
set(ALL_OPTIONS FIRST_OPT;SECOND_OPT;THIRD_OPT)
foreach(option IN LISTS ALL_OPTIONS)
    if(${option})
        math(EXPR COUNTER "${COUNTER+1}")
    endif()
endforeach()

if(NOT ${COUNTER})
    message("No option was chosen")
elseif(${COUNTER} GREATER 1)
    message("More than one option was chosen")
endif()
```